# Spring security returns wrong loggedin user AFTER override UserDetailsContextMapper

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap

I am using **spring security with LDAP** in a spring boot application.

Everything was working fine **before** I did below changes in security config as below.

1. Override **UserDetailsContextMapper** to set ROLE for the users.
2. **Restrict URLs** based on user role.

Below are the code changes to achieve above 2 things.

**1. UserDetailsContextMapper:**

```
@Component
public class UserDetailsContextMapperImpl implements UserDetailsContextMapper, Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3962976258168853954L;
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDetailsContextMapperImpl.class);


    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authority) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

            try{
                Attributes attrListOuter = ctx.getAttributes();
                Attribute attrListInner = attrListOuter.get(UserConstant.MEMBER_OF);
                logger.info("memberOf: " + attrListInner.getID());
                for (NamingEnumeration enumInner = attrListInner.getAll(); enumInner.hasMore();){
                      String CN = (String)enumInner.next();
                      logger.info("CN value: " + CN);
                      if(CN.contains(UserConstant.MASTER_GROUP_PROJ_NAME)){
                          logger.info("Logged in user is authorized to acccess Rates Toronto application: {}", username );
                          mappedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(UserConstant.ROLE_ABC));// adding ROLE_ABC to APP/LDAP users.
                          logger.info("User {} Role set as : {}", username, UserConstant.ROLE_ABC );
                          break;
                      }else if(CN.contains(UserConstant.GROUP_XYZ)){
                          mappedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(UserConstant.ROLE_XYZ));
                          logger.info("User {} Role set as : {}", username, UserConstant.ROLE_XYZ );
                          break;
                      }
                   }

                  if(mappedAuthorities.isEmpty()){
                        logger.info("Logged in user is NOT authorized to access ABCD application : {}", username );
                   }

            }catch(Exception ex){
                logger.info("Exception while mapping UserDetails with LDAP" + ex.getMessage());
            }
        //Returning Spring Seurity's User object.
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, "", true, true, true, true, mappedAuthorities);

    }
```

**2. Restrict URLs based on user role:**

In my websecurity configuration class,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AbcWebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

.......

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").hasAnyRole("REST","ABC").and().httpBasic().and().formLogin(); 
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/xyz/**").hasRole("XYZ").and().httpBasic(); 
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/abc/**").hasRole("ABC").and().httpBasic(); // Users who are accessing the URLS/application via application's UI. ie. Business User.
        http.headers().contentTypeOptions().xssProtection().cacheControl().httpStrictTransportSecurity().frameOptions().disable();
        http.headers().addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Cache-Control","no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"));
        http.headers().addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Expires","0"));
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
        super.configure(http);
    }
```

and ......

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.ldapAuthentication().userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapperImpl).userSearchFilter(SAM_ACC).userSearchBase(base).contextSource().url(url).managerDn(managerDn).managerPassword(password);
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(restUserName).password(restPassword).roles(restRole);
    //This publisher will trigger AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent (AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent)
    auth.authenticationEventPublisher(new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher));
}
```

**After** the above changes, getting loggedIn user giving **wrong** user ( **sometimes**),

This is **not** happening every-time, but happening intermittently.

I am using below code to get the **current logged in user**.

`Authentication authentication = securityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null)
            return null;
        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User userDetails = (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        String userName = userDetails.getUsername();`

I am unable to find where I am missing, any pointers/direction will be very helpful.

It is returning wrong user from **already authenticated** users.

I am using spring boot **1.2.0** which uses **spring security 3.2.5** by default

Comment: It is returning wrong user from already authenticated users.

Comment: Just to get a better picture of things, what web framework (if any) are you using? Version of spring/spring security?

Comment: I am using spring boot 1.2.0 which uses spring security 3.2.5 by default